# Iphone 4 won't turn on and home button does not work

Tags: iphone

My iPhone is dead in black screen.

I was walking on the street when it was the last time i used the iphone normally. The next time back home, i realized that after trying to use the phone again by pressing just once on the turn on/ wake button, the phone was dead. I plugged the charger and i could clearly hear the sound of charging. Then i tried switching the silent button and i could felt the vibrator when you unlock the silence button. Then i heard someone calling or sending me a message.

I have watched and read lots of tutorials where most of them say it can be solved by pressing on both the home and turn on buttons at the same time for about 6 - 20 seconds... **but my problem is that the home button does not work at all since long time ago**. So i can't try that possibility :/

How can i get it back working? Any ideas?

Comment: Hold home and power on/wake until your phone restarts.

Comment: @Tyson read "that the home button does not work at all since long"

Comment: so you are still driving that car with flat tire ? :)

Comment: 1. Take phone to shop, ask them to fix broken button. 2. Try holding power/home until it restarts. 3. Take phone back to shop, ask them to check screen.

Comment: @Tetsujin, thanks. I followed your advice by visiting a shop and now i got it working again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I went to a shop where there is a specialized department for iphone/ipad repairments (as suggested by @Tetsuiin). They told me the display was no longer working and it had to be replaced. They also replaced the home button. Now i got my iphone 4 back working like a charm again.

**By the way**, i have noticed that my battery lasts more time. Looks like this new display uses less energy ;)

Answer (score 1):

One thing I would recommend you doing is connect your iPhone to a computer and download Recboot from [here](http://www.cydiageeks.com/recboot-enter-exit-recovery-mode-iphone.html). This tool allows you to go into recovery mode and get out of it should fix the problem. If not, restore from iTunes.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution a colleague did at my iPhone4:

- Use medical alcohol at a very high percent rate, e.g. > 80%
- Be sure your iPhone is switched OFF.
- Take a pipette and pour a good amount of alcohol on your Home button, so the alcohol can creep in the slit. Do not drown it! The alcohol must NOT get in the dock connector!
- Wait 3mins.
- Start hitting and releasing the Home button at least 100 times, starting slow and with a little force, lessening force when it gets lighter...

If you are done and have the feeling, the Home button is fully functional again, let your iPhone lie on the table for 1-2h, power it on and - tadaaaaa! - you have your Home button back. :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try doing hard reset your device ? Most of the issues are fixed by hard reset and Many people found that it solves minor bugs too. If you tried it and still facing then you might need to try to take it to Apple Care or just try installing firmware by entering into recovery mode with help of [Recboot](http://www.cydiatechie.com/143/download-recboot-windows-mac-linux.html).